# Modify file received from other server

Tags: php, forms, zip

I'm making a website and my page is in PHP and posts a form to another website which returns a zip file which the browser downloads directly. But the problem is that one file needs to be added to the zip. So how can I save the zip to my website to modify it before it's getting downloaded?

Comment: Just like you said: you save the file, unpack it and create a new zip archive packing all unpacked files into it _plus_ the one you want to add. What is the problem here? _What have you tried so far_?

Answer (score 1):

If the action of the form is pointing to another site, then there is no way for you to manipulate the response.

You need to change your form to post to *your own site*, then have your server make the HTTP request to the other site, parse the response, edit the zip file and then return it to the client.